# Change the content of a H1 tag while scrolling in another section - Using IntersectionObserver?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 sections on my website each section has a fullscreen height in css of `min-height: 100vh` and each section has a unique color.

Created a fixed block which is set to the bottom with a width of 100%. Inside this fixed div I have a section title.

Now, I am trying to change this section title text based on the current in viewport DIV. I want to give each section a unique section title to let visitors know which section is currently visible.

But I noticed scrolling down with the Oberserver works fine but scrolling up works only If you reach the top of the first section.

My CSS:

```
section {
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-items: center;
}
```

My HTML:

```
Fixed div:

// The Section title should be dynamic based on the data attribute: `data-section-title`
<div class="fixed-bar"><h2 class="section--title"><!-- innerHTML --></div>

<section id="intro" data-section-title="Intro">Content</section>
<section id="about" data-section-title="About">Content</section>
<section id="services" data-section-title="Services">Content</section>
<section id="contact" data-section-title="Contact">Content</section>
```

Is there a clean and nice way to solve this?

Comment: At what point do you want the title in the fixed section to change? e.g. when more than half the viewport is taken up by a section, or when a section first starts to come into view or... Could you show us how you set up the intersection observer?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet sets the IntersectionObserver to trigger if just over half of a section is visible. When it does, the title is copied to the fixed div.

The IntersectionObserver doesn't have to do anything when a section's visibility drops below the threshold.

```js
let options = {
  threshold: 0.51
}
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document.querySelector('.section--title').innerHTML = entry.target.getAttribute('data-section-title');
    }
  });
};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('[data-section-title]');
for (let i = 0; i< sections.length; i++) {
  observer.observe(sections[i]);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-items: center;
}
#intro { background: cyan; }
#about { background: magenta; }
#services { background: yellow; }
#contact { background: lime; }

.fixed-bar {
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background: #eeeeee;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" data-section-title="Intro">Content</section>
<section id="about" data-section-title="About">Content</section>
<section id="services" data-section-title="Services">Content</section>
<section id="contact" data-section-title="Contact">Content</section>

<div class="fixed-bar"><h2 class="section--title"><!-- innerHTML --></h2></div>
```

Comment: Hi this works but the problem actually is that the fixed bar is at the top set 0. The class change fires too early. It should only fire if the fixed div from slides inside/over a next div and same when you scroll up from bottom the class should change.

Comment: Hi, I don’t think I’m understanding. You can change the amount an element has to be showing, I just put 60% but that can be any proportion.

Comment: If the fixed section--title on scroll enters another section it just change. Now it is changing like 20% earlier.

Answer (score -1):

This takes the element from the center of the screen using the `document.elementFromPoint` method.

```js
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
  var elementAtPos = document.elementFromPoint(window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2);
  if(elementAtPos) {
    document.querySelector("h2.section--title").innerText = elementAtPos.getAttribute("data-section-title");
  }
}
```

```css
section {
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-items: center;
 border: 2px solid red;
}

.fixed-bar {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bar"><h2 class="section--title">Content</h2></div>

<section id="intro" data-section-title="Intro">Content</section>
<section id="about" data-section-title="About">Content</section>
<section id="services" data-section-title="Services">Content</section>
<section id="contact" data-section-title="Contact">Content</section>
```

You could change where the element is taken from.
There might be issues with overlays and older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('yourid').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    //Your code to change the h1 tag
})
```